# Query unique items with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a database of cars:

```
make, model, year, color
```

I want to find all cars from "Dodge" but do not show me the same model twice:
For example, I may have:

```
Dodge,van,2004,red
Dodge,van,2005,blue
Dodge,ram,2005,blue
GM,Sunfire,2006,red
```

If I do:

```
Car.where(make:"Dodge",model: $UNIQUE)
```

I expect to get:

```
Dodge,van,2004,red
Dodge,ram,2005,blue
```

Ofcourse $UNIQUE does not exist... how can this be done with active record / sql?

More generally, I want all objects where x == y && z is unique in results set.

This can be done with some ruby by doing Car.where(make: "Dodge").all then pruning out duplicate models, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: How should it decide which one to show, or are you only concerned with the "Dodge" part?

Comment: Why don't you expect one random Dodge Van and the Dodge Ram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should return random cars with unique make/model combinations (a Dodge Van and Dodge Ram):

```
Car.where(make: 'Dodge').group(:model)
```

If you are just interested in any Dodge and don't care about the model at all (this is not clear from your question) then this might fit your needs:

```
Car.where(make: 'Dodge').first
```